# Uploading to a folder other than root in Dropbox with SharpBox

Tags: c#, cloud, dropbox, sharpbox

I am having a problem to upload to any folder other than root in Dropbox using SharpBox. I can upload using this path `var publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/");`, but not to folder created in root, such as "/MyFolder". I can enumerate files using this path `var publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/MyFolder");`, but not upload there. Exception says: not authorized. How do I assign permissions to folders in root or is the problem in the app permissions? I appreciate any help.

Steps:

1. Created account
2. Created app on Dropbox with Full dropbox access
3. Created console application in C#
4. Installed Sharpbox using NuGet
5. Generated token using keys provided by the app
6. Coded

Here is the code:

```
        CloudStorage dropBoxStorage = new CloudStorage();

        var dropBoxConfig = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox);

        ICloudStorageAccessToken accessToken = null;

        // load security token from file
        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"<<token file location>>", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            accessToken = dropBoxStorage.DeserializeSecurityToken(stream);
        }

        // open connection 
        var storageToken = dropBoxStorage.Open(dropBoxConfig, accessToken);


        var publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/MyFolder"); 

        //upload file
        dropBoxStorage.UploadFile("<<source path>>", publicFolder);


        dropBoxStorage.Close();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing .NET Framework from 4.5 to 4 solved my problem.